# Failed to start The Apache HTTP Server - Unit apache2.service has failed

Tags: systemd, apache-httpd, services

I recently installed Apache2 via `sudo apt install apache2` but it doesn't seem to be working right. I get this error when I try to restart the service using `sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 restart`. I'm using Kubuntu 18.04.1 64-bit.

```
-- Subject: Unit apache2.service has begun start-up
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://www.ubuntu.com/support
-- 
-- Unit apache2.service has begun starting up.
Aug 29 13:31:47 alpaca-desktop apachectl[10871]: AH00558: apache2: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using 127.0.1.1. Set the 'ServerName' di
Aug 29 13:31:47 alpaca-desktop apachectl[10871]: (2)No such file or directory: AH02291: Cannot access directory '/var/log/apache2/' for main error log
Aug 29 13:31:47 alpaca-desktop apachectl[10871]: (2)No such file or directory: AH02291: Cannot access directory '/var/log/apache2/' for error log of vhost defined at /etc/apache2
Aug 29 13:31:47 alpaca-desktop apachectl[10871]: AH00014: Configuration check failed
Aug 29 13:31:47 alpaca-desktop apachectl[10871]: Action 'start' failed.
Aug 29 13:31:47 alpaca-desktop apachectl[10871]: The Apache error log may have more information.
Aug 29 13:31:47 alpaca-desktop systemd[1]: apache2.service: Control process exited, code=exited status=1
Aug 29 13:31:47 alpaca-desktop systemd[1]: apache2.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Aug 29 13:31:47 alpaca-desktop systemd[1]: Failed to start The Apache HTTP Server.
-- Subject: Unit apache2.service has failed
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://www.ubuntu.com/support
-- 
-- Unit apache2.service has failed.
-- 
-- The result is RESULT.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the reason:

```
(2)No such file or directory: AH02291: Cannot access directory '/var/log/apache2/' for main error log
```

If that directory doesn't exist, then how can Apache start? And if it does, then the user designated for Apache can't access it, which means  the file permissions are incorrect.

Comment: `mkdir: cannot create directory ‘/var/log/apache2’: File exists`

Comment: Ok, well maybe try moving that file elsewhere and creating a directory. I would check to see if there is any contents in the file first..

Comment: I purged and re-installed apache2 and the problem changed, now it's saying that it can't bind to address because the address is already in use. Should I post a separate question? These seem like separate issues.

Comment: Just kill the PID then try starting Apache.... It seems like you had it running at some point and the PID was hung..

Comment: You running this as root or atleast w/ sudo privs? If not, netstat will not provide the PID that is binding to port 80. From the looks of it, something is in fact binding to port 80.

Comment: There was indeed something bound, I killed it and it worked. Tip: Netstat must be run with root or it won't work!

Comment: Correction: it will work, but not as intended when you are trying to reveal what PID(s) is bound to the port